# Printing landscape html->pdf using abcPDF

Tags: html, css, landscape, abcpdf

I am trying to get a PDF generated by abcPDF from html output to print the first three pages in portrait and then switch the fourth page to landscape.

I have been able to get the html to switch into landscape for the fourth page by applying this class to a div that is the 4th page:

```
.PageLandscape {
    width="100%";
    height="100%";
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(Rotation=3);
    size:landscape;
}
```

When abcPDF converts the html to pdf though, the 4th page is still portait.

Any thoughts or hints?

thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you've found the answer, but here's how I did it. Found it from ABCpdf docs:

http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/4-examples/08-landscape.htm

I think you can apply the transformation per page. But because you set rotation on the document as a whole (when you save) not sure you can do it on a per page basis.

Comment: This URL is changed. I believe the correct URL today is http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/4-examples/08-landscape.htm

Answer (score 1):

[ABCpdf seems to sometimes ignore style-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104635/abcpdf-document-not-applying-css).
Maybe you could you try an inline style-element?